# Local variable 'timer' value is not used

Tags: python, scope

```py
def start(timer):
    global minuti
    canvas.itemconfig(second_text, text=f"0{timer}")
    window.after(1000, start, timer + 1)
    if len(str(timer)) < 2:
        print(timer)
        canvas.itemconfig(second_text, text=f"0{timer}")
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(second_text, text=timer)
    if timer / 10 == 1:
        timer = 0     
        minuti = minuti + 1
        if len(str(minuti)) < 2:
            canvas.itemconfig(minute_text, text=f"0{minuti}")
        else:
            canvas.itemconfig(minute_text, text=minuti)
```

Hello, I have this code, and when the timer is equal to 10 I want to reset it to 0.
The code above is not working properly, the line of code "timer = 0" is saying "Local variable 'timer' value is not used".
I think is a Scope problem, but i'm not sure.

Can somebody help me??

PS: i've tried to change : timer = 0 with window.after(1000, start, timer - 10) and is working... Can somebody explain why this is working?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, this is a warning from your IDE. After this line, `timer = 0`, `timer` is not used again (you don't use it for the rest of the function) so your IDE is just letting you know that this assignment to 0 is sort of pointless. If your goal of this function is to have the value of `timer` change after the function is called you will have an issue because Python uses pass-by-sharing meaning mutable types like ints/floats/etc. will not be changed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer,but how do i change that value then? 
window.after(1000, start, timer + 1) <---- This line of code is working, and the timer is going +1 every second. When it is 10 I need to set it to 0. 
Can you give me a help?

Comment: @FabioLentini I have provided a very basic example of how you can work around this issue. I recommend you implement a `timer` class to make this code cleaner, but this is functional.

Comment: Thank you, i fix it changing that line with " window.after(1000, start, timer - 10)", but still I dont get why this line is working..

Comment: @FabioLentini what line did you change? I do not understand what your fix was.

Comment: @FabioLentini I think if I understood what you are trying to accomplish with this code I could help you better - you currently have a sort of confusing recursive function but I do not understand the goal.